# Pointer to QVector of pointers

Tags: qt, pointers, qvector

I  have a pointer to the QVector of pointers. I need to pass "trigger" as a reference.

I have this in header:

```
public:
    QVector<Trigger*>* triggers;
```

What do I have to input where ??? are (triggers[i] is not ok):

```
void FastViveLoop::solveTriggers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < triggers->count(); ++i)
    {
        bool on, off;
        on = checkOn(???);        
    }
}

bool FastViveLoop::checkOn(Trigger &trigger)
{


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since `triggers` is a member variable why make it a raw pointer in the first place?

Comment: Because I have QVector<Trigger*> in some other class and this is only to do some work on the data.

Comment: `trigger* ptr = (*vptr)[i]; fun(*ptr);`, but this is horrible design that circumvents a lot of things - I recommend restructuring your code instead.

Comment: don't store a pointer to QVector, work with a reference on the method when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like that you are storing a QVector as a pointer,
this is not how this class should be used.
But since you are, there's an easy way to solve your issue.

```
void FastViveLoop::solveTriggers()
{
    for(auto item : (*trigger))
    {
        bool on, off;
        on = checkOn(item);        
    }
}
```

Use use the range-based for with the value of the QVector.